# Question mark syntax from CoffeeScript without CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

CoffeeScript has such syntax sugar:

```
item.getFoo?().fooParam?.bar
```

Which translates into long javascript equivalent with `getFoo==null` and `fooParam==null` checks. The question is: are there any ways to use this syntax in vanilla javascript with a library/translator/compiler other than CoffeeScript? We use Traceur in our project, but it doesn't have such syntax because it is not ES6 compliant (although I wish it to). Maybe some way to implement it within Traceur fork?

Comment: have you tried to fork it? where are the problems?

Comment: It seems to be too hard for me to learn inner Traceur workings for implementing this little feature only.

Comment: yeah, I looked at it and it seems really complicated. Are you running compiled javascript on the client or are you shipping the compiler to the client? (do you have a `<script src="path/to/traceur.js">` in your code?)

Comment: Additionally, you might have clashes with the ternary operator (`…?…:…`) which is redefined in coffeescript to `if … then … else…`

Comment: in vanilla: (x=item.getFoo) && (x=x().fooParam) && x.bar; not as short as coffee, but a heck of a lot better than a bunch of ==nulls...

Comment: Maybe possible with something like sweet.js?

Comment: There's also [this](https://github.com/letsgetrandy/brototype) which may help.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal Brototype looks totally like an extension I would use in a production environment.

Comment: You can rename the methods to be more professional https://github.com/letsgetrandy/brototype#bro-tie

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want the exact CoffeeScript semantics, you can cheat a bit:

```
return item.getFoo ? (item.getFoo().fooParam || {}).bar : undefined;
```

There are a few tricks going on here.

1. The ternary operator is used to test the truthiness of `item.getFoo`
2. If `fooParam` is missing, falsey, or absent, we substitute it with an empty object. CoffeeScript would have bailed out here.
3. We return the value of `bar` regardless of whether it exists. If it does exist, you get the value you want. If it doesn't exist but `fooParam` is set, you get `undefined`. If it doesn't exist because `fooParam` was undefined and we fell back to `{}`, you still get `undefined`.

You can write some helpers if the ternary operator gets in the way:

```
function defaultObject(input) { // A helper to put somewhere
    return input || {};
}

return defaultObject((item.getFoo || defaultObject)().fooParam).bar;
```

This is even trickier: `defaultObject` will return `{}` when called with `getFoo`, so you don't need a ternary operator around the function call. If `fooParam` isn't truthy, `defaultObject` will return another empty object, eliminating the need for another `||`. If `fooParam` is truthy, `defaultObject` behaves like the identity function and returns it.

I'm sure this could be golfed further down, but I'd recommend avoiding this pattern. Anyone reading your code will be fairly confused and blame you for making a mess in the codebase.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question recently, and I came here hoping for a better solution than my current one. If you're doing this frequently, it's easier to make a function to do it for you:

```
var qm = function(arg) {
  if (arg instanceof Object) return arg;
  return function(){};
};
```

Then to use it, you wrap your objects in it to make sure no error is raised. It starts to look ugly if there are many **q**uestion **m**arks on a line

```
qm(qm(item.getFoo)().fooParam).bar
```

Comment: Just realized that this completely breaks apart when context (`this`) comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

The [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` was introduced in ES2020.

```
obj.val?.prop
obj.val?.[expr]
obj.arr?.[index]
obj.func?.(args)
```

It is supported by the browsers of 91.81% of internet users as of 29 November 2021 according to https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining.